# How to get subref style such as Figure 1(a) when using cleveref with subfig?

Tags: cleveref, subfig

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{subrefformat=parens}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{\figurename}{\figurename}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{aaa}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{bbb}}
\caption{title}
\label{ccc}
\end{figure}

\figurename~\ref{aaa}
\figurename~\ref{bbb}
\figurename~\ref{ccc}

\figurename~\subref*{aaa}
\figurename~\subref*{bbb}

\cref{aaa}
\cref{bbb}
\cref{ccc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to use `\cref` with subfloat label to generate `1(a)` but not `1a`. Is there some simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *should* cover all the bases.

Basic idea: redefine `\thesubfigure` to include the parentheses (assuming you will never use the format without the parentheses), and fix everything else to match.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{\figurename}{\figurename}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup{lofdepth=2}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=simple,listofformat=subsimple,subrefformat=simple}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label[subfigure]{aaa}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label[subfigure]{bbb}}
\caption{title}
\label{ccc}
\end{figure}

\figurename~\ref{aaa}
\figurename~\ref{bbb}
\figurename~\ref{ccc}

\figurename~\subref*{aaa}
\figurename~\subref*{bbb}

\figurename~\subref{aaa}
\figurename~\subref{bbb}

\cref{aaa}
\cref{bbb}
\cref{ccc}

\end{document}
```

[image]